# Generate combined sinusoidal waveform (fundamental, 2nd, 3rd...) using PWM

Tags: pwm, harmonics, sinusoidal

I know that I can make sinusoidal waveform using SPWM, but how can I combine fundamental signal with different frequency signal (2nd, 3rd...) on a single signal created by SPWM?

Comment: Do you use a table of sinus values or do you calculate each PWM value directly?

Comment: Can you clarify: do you mean to add harmonics to an already existent SPWM signal, or to the harmonic, itself, to be further processed with PWM? E.g. (sin1 + sin2)->PWM, or (sin1->PWM)+sin2.

Comment: "SPWM" is just "PWM" which is being fed the digital values of the points along a sine wave. If you want to add harmonics to the signal, then you do so in the digital domain where you create/lookup/calculate the sine wave values for each point in time and then feed these values into the PWM instead of the 'plain' sine values.

Answer (score 2):

You can synthesize any waveform that you wish using PWM within certain limits which I will enumerate below. Generating a single frequency SIN wave is done by setting the PWM duty cycle on the fly in proportion to the amplitude of the SIN wave. Synthesizing another waveform would be done the same way. Knowing the amplitude levels that the waveform will have you simply set the PWM duty cycle on the fly proportional to that amplitude.

Now for the limitations:

1. Your fundamental PWM frequency needs to be higher than the highest frequency component in the signal that you want to synthesize. The more amplitude samples applied to the PWM duty cycle the more faithful the resulting waveform will be.
2. The clocking that generates the PWM signal places limits on the number of steps that can be used to represent the PWM duty cycle. For example an 8-bit PWM generator in an MCU can produce 254 distinct duty cycle values (ignoring the two states for 0% and 100% duty cycle) and a complex waveform to be synthesized may not be able to have its amplitude translated to duty cycle accurately represent the desired waveform.
3. Typical waveforms that are synthesized by PWM are periodic in nature thus it is straight forward to use a pre-computed lookup table of PWM duty cycle values to produce such waveform simply by repeatedly stepping through the table. An arbitrary function may not be easily represented as a periodic function within a reasonable sized table (many low level microcontrollers have limited memory although that is getting to be less and less of an issue with the advent of 32-bit MCUs).
4. If a lookup table cannot be used then it becomes necessary to compute the waveform amplitude and corresponding PWM duty cycle on the fly. Compute time could be longer that the sampling time needed to produce the waveform faithfully. (Refer to item 1 above). Calculation of trig functions on low level MCUs could be a good example of this limitation. So can you compute fast enough?
5. It is typical that a PWM synthesized waveform is filtered using an analog circuit (R and C circuit is common). This smooths the synthesized waveform and typically needs to be tuned to the synthesized waveform characteristics. The more complex the waveform the less effective the filter will be unless more complicated circuits are used. (Note that not all applications require a smoothing circuit. The load being driven by the PWM signals may itself be the smoothing element such as when driving a motor).

Answer (score 0):

Let say you want to generate a 50 Hz sinusoidal wave via PWM. The frequency of the PWM must be much higher, say 20 times faster. So your PWM frequency is 1000 Hz, and every cycle (period) is 1 ms.

Every millisecond you calculate the new value for the PWM active part. To do this, you must use the sin() function (or you can precalculate a table). For example, you keep a counter "t" which is zeroed when it reaches 1000. Then you calculate something like sin(t / k * ...).

Now, if you want to add another (lower) frequency, you simply calculate another sin(), but on a different time, i.e. sin(t / 2 / k * ...), and add the two sin() values together. This sin(t/2 ...) will add a wave at half the frequency.

Note that I reversed the things: I started with the higher frequency and added a lower one. This is because the frequency of the PWM must be much greater (say, 100 or 1000 times) than the *highest* frequency you want to synthetize.

If you simply add the two sin() together, the two generated frequencies will have the same amplitude. If you divide the result of sin() for 2, that wave will have half the amplitude.

I am too lazy to do the calculations now, I hope this explanation is enough to get you started.

Answer (score -1):

If you add many sines and cosines you end up with another function.

In fact for a function f(t) if the time domain of the function is finite you can construct it with addition of sines and cosines and some costant.

Comment: But how can i can make PWM that can create it?

Comment: if you add all these sines and cosines you will end up with a approximation of a different signal .Find that signal and make it using PWM.